How to read from external file and compare to given string
I am trying to extract text from an external file (someexternalfile.txt) and compare it with a given string (sometext) but it is saying that the external text and the given string are not the same (even though they should be).
LaTeX:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newread\myread
\openin\myread=someexternalfile.txt

\begin{document}

\read\myread to \myreadline
\ifx{\myreadline}{sometext}{Same.}\else{Not same.}\fi

\end{document}

someexternalfile.txt:
sometext

How can I solve this?

\ifx{\myreadline compares { to \myreadline so is only true if that was defined by \let\myreadline={


\ifx compares meanings of two tokens, thus \ifx{\myreadline compares the meaning of the token {1 to the meaning of the token \myreadline. Meanings of these tokens differ, thus TeX skips ahead until encountering the token right behind the matching \else which is  }2—\if..-\else-\fi-matching is independent from group-matching.
The reading apparatus of TeX is in state M (middle of line) after reading and tokenizing the phrase sometext while the category code of the carriage-return character is 5(end of line). Thus the carriage-return character appended due to the \endlinechar-mechanism yields a space token which also makes it into the replacement text of the macro \myreadline. You can turn off the \endlinechar-mechanism via \endlinechar=-1\relax.

\begin{filecontents*}{someexternalfile.txt}
sometext
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newread\myread
\openin\myread=someexternalfile.txt

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\endlinechar=-1\relax
\global\read\myread to \myreadline
\endgroup

\def\sometext{sometext}
\def\someothertext{someothertext}

\ifx\myreadline\sometext Same.\else Not same.\fi

\ifx\myreadline\someothertext Same.\else Not same.\fi

\end{document}


You also need to add a space at the end.  It is good idea to check the catcode using \meaning.
\begin{filecontents*}{someexternalfile.txt}
sometext
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newread\myread
\openin\myread=someexternalfile.txt

\begin{document}

\read\myread to\myreadline
(\myreadline)

\def\test{sometext }%
\ifx\myreadline\test\relax Same.\else Not same.\fi

\end{document}

